# Rails model association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to design model associations in rails
that consist of the following 3 types:

Commentator, Blogpost and Comment

--> it's "Commentator" and not "User" what means
that they are not the users who create blogposts...
instead they create comments only.

While the basic relationship between Commentator
and Comment is obvious:

```
class Commentator < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to: comments
```

I am not sure how to relate "Blogpost" to this...
--> I would like go be able to ask for all the Blogposts 
a Commentator has left as well as all the Commentators
of a specific Blogpost.

Since this is a many-to-many relationship I 
would use:

```
class Commentator < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments
    has_many :blogposts, :through => :comments

class Blogpost < ActiveRecord::Base
    "has_many :commentators, :through => :comments
```

When a commentator creates a blogpost, do I have to
write the commenentator_id and blogpost_id in comments
by myself into the corresponding fields of the comment table?

I think it would be better to have Blogposts as the 
going through element since the relationship could be 
automatically be build when a commentator creates a comment.
(apart from the fact that commentators cannot create comments
to Blogposts that do not exist...)
But then, Commentator to Comment would NOT be a many-to-many
relationship and I cannot use "has_many ... through" anymore.

What is a good way to relate this 3 types of models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution to the stated problem**

```
class Commentator < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_many :blogposts, :through => :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :commentator 
  belongs_to  :blogpost  
end

class Blogpost < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_many :commentators, :through => :comments
  belongs_to :user

class User
  has_many :blogposts
end
```

To add a comment to an existing blog post (assuming we have a `blog` and `commentator` variables)

```
blog.comments.create(:commentator => commentator, :comment => "foo bar")
```

OR

```
commentator.comments.create(:blog => blog, :comment => "foo bar")
```

**Note**

Instead of using two models for users(i.e. User and Commenter), I would use one model and assign privileges
to distinguish between a commentor and a blog post writer.

```
class User
  has_many :blogs
  has_many :comments
  has_many :commented_blogs, :through => :comments, :source => :blog
end

class Blog
  has_many :comments
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :commenters, :through => :comments, :source => :user
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :blog
end
```

- Creating a blog entry:

  ```
  if current_user.has_role?(:blog_writer)
    current_user.blogs.create(params[:blog])
  end
  ```
- Adding a comment:

  ```
  current_user.comments.create(:blog => blog, :content => "foor bar")
  ```

  **OR**

  ```
  blog.comments.create(:user => current_user, :content => "foor bar")
  ```